# Getting Frequency of words from Twitter Data (by dates)

Tags: python, twitter, mapreduce, nlp

I have live twitter stream data which I have filtered. It looks like this:

2017-01-26 india RT @bnowalk: I wish the Democrats in office had the courage of a South Dakota national park social media intern.

2017-01-26 india I don't have it non-intrusive.

2017-01-27 india From zero to distributed datastore

2017-01-27 india Mercedes-Benz Unimog – the all-rounder via @myvan_com

2017-01-27 india RT @TONewcomer: Interested in mentoring a newcomer or refugee artist? Contact @NANToronto @TorontoArts @TOArtsFdn #cdnimm…

2017-01-28 india My queen, my Miss Universe 2016. Queen Maxine, wish you luck #MissUniverse2016 #Philippines #4M4MU

2017-01-28 india 2 people followed me and one person unfollowed me // automatically checked by

2017-01-28 india multiple sex partner

I want my output to look like this:

2017-01-27 2

2017-01-28 3

2017-01-26 3

This is what I have written till now:

```
total = 0

with open('pp.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        finded = line.find('india')
        if finded != -1 and finded != 0:
            total += 1

print (total)
```

I don't know how to proceed from here to get the frequency of the word "india" in a particular date.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well you need to have a way to store these by date so we need some container.  I am going to use a dictionary

```
date_dict = dict()

with open(with open('pp.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        date = line[0:10]
        india_count = line.lower().count('india'):
        if date in date_dict:
            date_dict[date] += india_count
        else:
            date_dict[date] = india_count
```

So that gets your dates and frequencies into a data structure.  But to get it out you need to reorganize it a bit given what you want

so lets convert the data to a list of tuples and then sort it by the date:

First get the date and frequencies into a list - we are going to create a list of tuples for each key (date) in the dictionary the value will be the frequency of the word india.

```
my_dates = [(k,v) for k,v in date_dict.items()]
```

Then  sort by date - here we are sorting by the first (0th) value in each tuple

```
my_dates.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[0])
```